# radio button asp.net highlight div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net

Below my code is meant to highlight the title and footer divs when the respective radio button is clicked but i cant get it to work. i have used Jquery.

```
<div class="radio-group-row">
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label_EveningWeekend" AssociatedControlID="RadioButton_EveningWeekend">
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Panel_Package1" CssClass="package-container">
            <div class="package-title">Free Evening & Weekend</div>
            <div class="package-body">
                <h4>£16.75</h4>
                <p>Lorum ipsum</p>
            </div>
            <div class="package-footer">
                <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="RadioButton_EveningWeekend" GroupName="Package" OnCheckedChanged="Radio_List_Packages_OnSelectedIndexChanged" ClientIDMode="Static" />
            </div>
        </asp:Panel>
    </asp:Label>
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" AssociatedControlID="RadioButton_Anytime">
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Panel_Package2" CssClass="package-container">
            <div class="package-title">Free Evening & Weekend</div>
            <div class="package-body">
                <h4>£16.75</h4>
                <p>Lorum ipsum</p>
            </div>
            <div class="package-footer">
                <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="RadioButton_Anytime" GroupName="Package" OnCheckedChanged="Radio_List_Packages_OnSelectedIndexChanged" ClientIDMode="Static" />
            </div>
        </asp:Panel>
    </asp:Label>
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label2" AssociatedControlID="RadioButton_Data">
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Panel_Package3" CssClass="package-container">
            <div class="package-title">Free Evening & Weekend</div>
            <div class="package-body">
                <h4>£16.75</h4>
                <p>Lorum ipsum</p>
            </div>
            <div class="package-footer">
                <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="RadioButton_Data" GroupName="Package" OnCheckedChanged="Radio_List_Packages_OnSelectedIndexChanged" ClientIDMode="Static" />
            </div>
        </asp:Panel>
    </asp:Label>
</div>
```

and the jquery:

```
$("package-container").click(function () {
    $(this).parent('radio-group-row').find('label').removeClass('highlight');
    $(this).find('input:radio').attr('checked', true);
    $(this).find('label').addClass('highlight');
});
```

EDIT:

my css:

```
.package-container {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:#fff;
    margin-left: 1%;
    float: left;
    width: 32%;
}

.package-title {
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    height: 50px;
    background-color:#333;
}
.package-body {
    text-align: center;
    color: #666;
    height: 175px;
    padding-top: 10%;
    background-color:#fff0f5;
}
.package-footer {
    text-align: center;
    height: 25px;
    background-color:#333;
}
.highlight {
    background-color:red;
}
```

my question is how can i get the title and footer divs to change color when the radio button associated with it is clicked.

**EDIT**

```
$(".package-container").click(function () {
        $(this).closest('.radio-group-row').find('package-title').removeClass('package-title');  
        $(this).find('input:radio').prop('checked', true);  
        $(this).find('package-title').addClass('highlight'); 
    });
```

Comment: `$(this).parent('radio-group-row')` should be written `$(this).parent('.radio-group-row')` . Note the additional dot, referring to the `radio-group-row` class instead of a supposed `radio-group-row` element if you don't put the dot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your html structure you can fix your issues using the following:

```
//add dot to selector
$(".package-container").click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.radio-group-row').find('label').removeClass('highlight');  //add dot to selector and use closest
    $(this).find('input:radio').prop('checked', true);  //use prop instead of attr
    $(this).parent('label').addClass('highlight');  //use parent instead of find
});
```

**Summary of changes**

- Add dots to class selectors
- Change parent to closest as `radio-group-row` isn't the immediate parent of `package-container`
- change `attr` to `prop`
- change `.find('label')` to `parent` as the label is the parent of `package-container`, not a child

Comment: thanks for the areas to change. if i wanted the 'package-title' divs background-color to change would i use .child()?

Comment: you can either use `.children()` or `.find()` but ass you have already added a class of highlight to your label, you can just add an extra style to your stylesheet:  `.highlight .package-title {background-color: newColour;}`

Comment: I edited my question with my new jquery but it isnt changing the class of the product-title div

Comment: you forgot the dot again - `.find('.package-title')` also yuo are removing the class `package-title` or is that a copy and paste error

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this with `.selector` class selector:

```
$(".package-container").click(function () {
   $(this).parent('.radio-group-row').find('label').removeClass('highlight');
   $(this).find('input:radio').prop('checked', true);
   $(this).find('label').addClass('highlight');
});
```

and use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`

Answer (score 0):

You're not referencing your element classes correctly.  For example:

```
$("package-container")
```

should be:

```
$(".package-container")
```

Classes need to be prefixed with a `.` in selectors.  Without it, jQuery is looking for an *element* called `package-container`:

```
<package-container />
```

Since that doesn't exist, no matches are found and no handlers are created.

You have the same error here as well:

```
parent('radio-group-row')
```

(and possibly elsewhere in code not included in the question)